# PCIe Bit Lock in LTSSM Polling.Active

Tags: pcie

My understand of PCIe bit lock which is for Tx and Rx sync the clock and lock PLL clock at Rx side to latch data correctly. But how does it do it? Any protocol flow needed for bit lock to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The link starts with a training phase with a fixed pattern that the PLL can lock on to. That is part of the link protocol, the higher layers aren't involved.